# XML parsing in Retrofit Android

Tags: android, xml-parsing, retrofit2

I am new to Retrofit and trying to parse xml in it. I am posting my code what I have try so far.

```
 @FormUrlEncoded
 @POST
 Call<String> login(
        @Url String url,
        @Header("Authorization") String token,
        @Field("mobilenumber") String mobile);
```

Output:

```
<Login>
<ResponseCode>1001</ResponseCode>
<ResponseMessage>Something went wrong.Please try again</ResponseMessage>
<ReferenceId>135745</ReferenceId>
</Login>
```

I don't know how to specify Object and add annotations to it according to the structure of the xml file.